# Will ConcurrentLinkedQueue#poll() ever block?

Tags: java, concurrency

My thread runs forever and calls ConcurrentLinkedQueue#poll() after a ConcurrentLinkedQueue#peek().

But under some conditions, the thread seems to hang. I know this is a bit vague
but can people confirm for me that the methods poll() or peek() will **NEVER** block. Thanks.

Comment: Please post your code / unit test so we can both run and verify that something aspect of the code isn't causing the problem

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For what I can tell, the [ConcurrentLinkedQueue](http://java.sun.com/j2se/1.5.0/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ConcurrentLinkedQueue.html) is a "wait-free" implementation.

So I must assume that each independent call to `poll()` or `peek()` will **NEVER block**.

Atomic operations on this collection are synchronized and each individual call to the queue is guaranteed thread-safe.

There must be a problem with your code. For instance, if you do:

```
Object obj;

if (queue.peek() != null)
   obj = queue.poll()
```

Does not garentee that `obj` will not be `null`.

Answer (score 0):

According to the Javadoc, it seems that peek() and poll() should never block. I whipped up a quick producer/consumer test and I've gotten no blocking.

Answer (score 0):

I do not believe that your problem is due to this, but poll() and peek() can (at least theoretically) block:

As the name implies, ConcurrentLinkedQueue is implemented as a linked list. When polling or peeking, the implementation tries to start from the head and iterates through the linked nodes, trying to find a node that is not deleted. If it finds a non-empty node it returns that, if it reaches the end it returns that the queue is empty, but if it find a deleted node, it retries.

So consider this sequence. P is a producer thread, and we have two consumer threads C1 and C2:

```
P:  queue.add()
C1: starts queue.poll(), begins to inspect first node
C2: completes a queue.poll() removing the item.
P:  queue.add()
C1: continues inspecting the first node, notes that it is deleted. 
      Restarts and begins to inspect the new first node.
C2: completes a queue.poll() removing the item.
P:  queue.add()
C1: continues inspecting the first node, notes that it is deleted. 
      Restarts and begins to inspect the new first node.
etc.
```

So poll() and peek() will block until they can determine whether or not the queue is empty.

But unless you are using some very strange thread-priorities, this scenario is **highly** unlikely, and I would recommend you look elsewhere for your bug.